# A one-liner for finding the index of an element that has certain class within a jQuery set of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an arbitrary structure like this:

```
<h2>Foo</h2>
<p>Foo foo</p>
<p>Foofoo</p>

<h2>Bar</h2>

<h2 class=highlighted>Baz</h2>
<p>Baz</p>

<h2>Quux</h2>
<p>Quux quux</p>
```

In my JS i already have all h2 elements in a jQuery object:

```
var $headings = $('h2');
```

Now i need to find which of those headings has the highlighted class.

So for the above structure the third heading is highlighted, so i expect to receive the answer 2 (JS counts from zero).

I've managed to solve this task with:

```
function foo($jQueryObject) {
  var number;
  $jQueryObject.each( function(index, element) {
    if ($(element).hasClass('highlighted')) {
      number = index;
      return false;
    }
  });
  return number;
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/acaGeJi/1/

But i'm sure there's a more elegant way, something like `$headings.index('.highlighted');`. Can you please suggest it?

Comment: dude, you're using jQuery. `$('h2.highlighted")`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: That gets you the element, not the index of the element.

Comment: question: what do you need the index for? (to prevent an XY question. Andrey indicates he needs to know which elements have the heading class. Knowing their index is not part of finding that out)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm building an implementation of tabs that allows an arbitrary HTML structure. So in the above example headings are tab labels and paragraphs are tab content. I've got tab labels in a jQuery colection. When a tab label is clicked, i want to know that label's number (e. g. 2nd label was clicked), so i can activate the tab with the same number.

Comment: This sounds like it should be a `data-target="idOfTargetTab"`, so that you don't rely on indexing magic. If you link the tab and its label when you create them, then you're done, and you don't need to rely on indexing magic.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The reason why i'm trying `index()` is that i don't want to pollute my HTML with information that is already available from widget's semantics. Also, generating unique ids for multiple widgets on one page requires extra effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `map` method to get the index:

```
var index = $jQueryObject.map(function(i, e){
  return e.hasClass('highlighted') ? i : null;
})[0];
```

You can also use the `index` method, but then you have to get the element to look for first, so that means that you look for it twice:

```
var index = $jQueryObject.index($jQueryObject.filter('.highlighted'));
```

Comment: Yay, the map trick is awesome. Am i right that "i" is the index from the original collection?

Comment: The index trick also works (with `find` substiteted by `filter`), surprisingly. I don't understand why it returns correct result while `$jQueryObject.filter('.highlighted').index()` returns a different result.

Comment: @Andrey'lolmaus'Mikhaylov: If you call `.index()` it will consider all siblings to the element, not only the `h2` elements.

Comment: And what about `$jQueryObject.index('.highlighted')`, why doesn't it work?

Comment: Oh, @suhail's answer helps to understand that. This would mean "which index does $jQueryObject have among .highlighted elements". Am i right?

Comment: @Andrey'lolmaus'Mikhaylov: Yes, that is correct. Well, to be specific, it's the first element in $jQueryObject, if there happened to be more than one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$.index` function

```
var search = $( ".highlighted" );
alert( "Index: " + $( "h2" ).index( search ) );
```

Comment: Index returns the number of an element within its siblings, not within a jQuery object.

Comment: I'm sorry, your solution IS valid.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$('.highlighted').index('h2');
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/suhailvs/bVGK9/2/)

Comment: This violates the requirement to use the existing $headings object.